# flexbox - issue with justify-content property

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem with `justify-content: space-between` in flexbox. I have 9 items overall and I want only three items in a single row. Row has about 1000px width and one item has 260px width. Without `justify-content` three items are just next to eachother in 3 rows. When I apply that property two last items in third row are offset to the left. Why is this happening?

Here's how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/lc10bq

Container has `display:flexbox` and `flex-flow: row wrap` property set.

Comment: ensure the styles of those 2 element.
because flex box won't cause this.

Comment: all items in flex container are the same.. thats why i just can't figure out whats going on..

Comment: Ok.. I found it... I'm using react. It seems like I left ';' somewhere in a code... EVIDENCE: http://prntscr.com/lc13vo

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the 'flex: **0** 0 30%;' in the items

Comment: Describe your answer well to get more comprehensive answer/s.